# Cannot use sudo with users that I added

Tags: linux, sudo, su

add new user **tom**

```
useradd -m -p 12345 -s /bin/bash -G wheel tom
```

switch user from root to tom

```
su tom
```

and tom cannot use sudo, even I type right password.

```
We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things:

    #1) Respect the privacy of others.
    #2) Think before you type.
    #3) With great power comes great responsibility.
```

[image]

```
/etc/sudoers
%wheel (ALL)=(ALL) ALL

/etc/pam.s/su uncommented
auth required pam_wheel.so

$ groups
tom wheel
```

Comment: Welcome. The error in your image is wrong password

Comment: @guillermochamorro     password is right

Comment: The sudo error when you have no privileges is `<user> is not in the sudoers file.   This incident will be reported.`

Comment: Try logging out the user and log in again and then try sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man useradd (8)`:

> -p, --password PASSWORD
>                 The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.

Look into `/etc/shadow` and you will see that the *encrypted* password is `12345`. So it's no wonder that your password is wrong.

You can change the password as root with

```
passwd tom
```

and it should work.